# R update table column based on search string from another table

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, dplyr

I am trying to update Cell B in a table based on the value of cell A in the same table.  To filter the rows I want to update I am using grepl to compare cell A to a list of character strings from a list/table/vector or some other external source.  For all rows where cell A matches the search criteria, I want to update cell B to say "xxxx". I need to do this for all rows in my table.

So far I have something like this where cat1 is a list of some sort that has strings to search for.

```
for (x in 1:length(cat1)){ 
  data %<>% mutate(Cat = ifelse(grepl(cat1[i],ItemName),"xxx",Cat))
}
```

I am open to any better way of accomplishing this. I've tried for loops with dataframes and I'm open to a data.table solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid the loop you can collapse the character vector with `|` and then use it as a single pattern in `grepl`, for example you can try:

```
cat1_collapsed <- paste(cat1, collapse = "|")
data %>% mutate(Cat = ifelse(grepl(cat1_collapsed, ItemName),"xxx", Cat))
```

Or the equivalent using data.table (or base R of course).

Comment: Thanks! This worked great.  The only thing I need to do now is find a way to do exactly this but loop for every collapsed cat that I have.  So for example cat1, cat2, cat3, etc... I'm thinking this will require using some sort of loop.  Also, I need to do the grepl matching on whole words.  So for example if my search term is "dog" i would want to match "fat dog", but not "doggy".

Comment: @user1991118, I won't update my answer unless you provide a minimal, self-contained reproducible example. If you do, I might see how to proceed. Also note that what you are asking now is not the original question.

Comment: I understand.  I will try to put something reproducible together and post to a new question. Thanks again.

Comment: @user1991118, you're welcome. Btw, you can say "thanks" by upvoting helpful answers or accepting the answer you liked best (if any).

Answer (score 2):

use the following code assuming that you have a data frame called "data" with column "A" and "B" and that "cat1" is a vector of the desired strings, as described

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)
data[A %in% cat1,B:="XXXX"]
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much.  I was able to get it setup and it is close, but instead of updating the columns, it is appending new rows with NA to the end of the data and updating B to "xxxx" for those added NA rows.  I need column B to be updated where there is a match for column A based on the values in the cat1 vector. I have experience with SQL and I'm new to R, but I see how useful it can be. Thanks again.